# URL Friendlly locations

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

im using in my website url friendly, the type of website i have is a Job board, so is important in the url use city, country, jobtype names to improve the website in search engine, the onlye problem is my htacess code doesnt look good and is taking me a lot of work. For example i have 100 cities, where one of them is "London"

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} londonjobs-(.*)-(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^jobs jobs.php?Location=%1&Category=%2 [L]
```

Now if i have 100 cities i had to put the code above 100 times, and this is horrible, how could i make that the "londonjobs" would be dynamic or let me change regarding of this content/text.

Comment: so make the city name a capture group as well: `(.*)jobs-(.*)-(.*)$`

Comment: What I have done, that isn't too different, is create a folder called something like 'lookup' so I can go to mysite.com/lookup/london/jobs/it/something/else/really/cool - then I can rewrite to replace "lookup/" with "lookup?q=" and have index.html in the lookup folder handle the request.